# Where can I find Twitter Bootstrap Variables for Sass?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'd like to use Twitter Bootstrap. But there is one thing I really like about the alternative Zurb Foundation. They are using plenty of Sass Variables for styling. Example:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html#available-scss-variables

```
$include-html-top-bar-classes: $include-html-classes;

/* Background color for the top bar */
$topbar-bg: #111;

/* Height and margin */
$topbar-height: 45px;
$topbar-margin-bottom: rem-calc(30);

/* Control Input height for top bar */
$topbar-input-height: 2.45em;

/* Controlling the styles for the title in the top bar */
$topbar-title-weight: bold;
$topbar-title-font-size: rem-calc(17);
```

I can't imagine, that Twitter isn't using such variables. Does anyone know, where to find those variables? Google didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twitter Boostrap with SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) is their official SASS support Github. They do fully support it, by the way.

See [Doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#sass) for details.

**Path & Description**

`lib/` Ruby gem code (Sass configuration, Rails and Compass integrations)

`tasks/` Converter scripts (turning upstream Less to Sass)

`test/` Compilation tests

`templates/` Compass package manifest

`vendor/assets/` Sass, JavaScript, and font files

`Rakefile` Internal tasks, such as rake and convert

[Master Variable File](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss)

Comment: Sorry. I might not phrased my question well enough. So please let me repeat it:

Where can I find Twitter Bootstrap Variables for Sass?

Comment: [Variables for SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) are there.

Comment: Thx. M8. :) This was what I was searching for.